# How to test Sequelize 'afterCreate' hook that sends email using nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sequelize.js, nodemailer

I have a `User` sequelize model that's loaded using the `index.js` file in the models directory e.g.

```
"use strict";

var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../../config/database.json')[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
   return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== basename);
 })
  .forEach(function(file) {
     var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
     db[model.name] = model;
 });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
   if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
   db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

 db.sequelize = sequelize;
 db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

 module.exports = db;
```

In my models `afterSave` hook:

```
afterCreate : function(user, options, fn){
  mailer.sendEmailConfirmation(user.email, user.confirmation_code,   function(err){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    fn(null, user);
  }
```

`mailer` is a dependency required in the model. How do I go about unit testing this? I basically want to save the user in a mocha test and ensure the `sendEmailConfirmation` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use mocking - either using a test library which mocks everything by default (http://facebook.github.io/jest/) or simply mock the function you care about, using a dedicated mocking / stubbing library such as [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs):

```
var stub = sinon.stub(mailer, 'sendEmailConfirmation', function (email ,code, fn) {
  fn(); // Your stub should invoke the callback, otherwise the hook will hang
});

user.save().then(function () {
  assert(stub.called())
});
```

Comment: How do I inject the stub into the Sequelize User model? That's the part that's troubling me the most. I think I should forgot about requiring all the models using the index.js file and require the User model on it's own. That way I could use something like proxyquire to replace the normal require call with my stub.

Comment: I depends a bit on your setup, but remember that requires are cached. So if your user model does `require mailer`, you can do the same in your tests, and stub the mailer there - the require is cached, so the two file (user and test) will have access to the same object. Which means that when you stub in test, user will also use the stubbed function

Comment: Will give the 'caching' method a try and see how I get on. Thanks!

Comment: If you find a way to get jest to work with sequelize... please let me know! I have tried and failed many times and now it is driving me insane!